# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am executing below code but i am getting the error. How to fix it..It i working fine in POSTMAN..in chrome it is throwing error

```
jscallout.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

JS -

```
<script>
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET","https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts");
request.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token","api-key 1234567890");
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET');
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
request.send();
request.onload = ()=>{
    console.log(request);
    if(request.status == 200) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(request.response));
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess it would require configuring server side, CORS is enabled at server side and accepting request from certain whitelisted url.